# .htaccess rule fails when including $ at end

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, mod-rewrite, regular-expression

#### The Basic Situation

We have a server.  It has some static files, some simple, "flat" `.php` and `.html` pages, but it also has a WordPress install at the document root, meaning that visiting `/` takes the user to the WordPress site.

The static files are at `/lp/`; however, I was recently tasked with rewriting the index of this folder as a WordPress page, such that its URL is preserved when accessed through WordPress.  WordPress auto-adds the following lines to `.htaccess` so that it handles any URLs that don't match existing files or folders:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

#### The Problem at Hand

The WordPress page at `/lp/` is written and published and set up with the proper link, but now it needs to be accessed through WordPress instead of as a flat file.  It would be fine and dandy for me to simply delete the content at `/lp/`, but some of it needs to be preserved, ideally with the existing links intact save for the very specific `/lp/` URL.  Thusly, I created my own section above the WordPress section:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^lp/?$   /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is with this expression right here:

```
^lp/?$
```

This doesn't seem to work.  It gives me the old page.  This, however *does* work:

```
^lp/?
```

The issue with this fix is that using it redirects any URL beginning with `lp/`, including those that might otherwise return flat or static content.

#### My Question

I figure there's something about the way WordPress or `mod_rewrite` works that I'm missing... but what is it, exactly?

Feel free to let me know if there's additional information I should include.

Answer (score 3):

> `RewriteRule ^lp/?$   /index.php [L]`

This fails to match because your actual URL is probably `/lp/index.php` (or whatever your `DirectoryIndex` is), not simply `/lp/`. (That is after Apache has internally mapped the URL to a filesystem path). So, try changing your `RewriteRule` *pattern*:

```
RewriteRule ^lp/index\.php$   /index.php [L]
```

Specifically, there is a conflict with mod_dir. It is common to run into these sorts of problems when trying to rewrite URLs that also exist as a physical directory on the filesystem.

When the request maps to a physical directory, mod_dir does a couple of things *before* mod_rewrite gets a look in.

1. If the request is missing a trailing slash then mod_dir appends the slash and *externally redirects*. (This depends on `DirectorySlash` being `On` - the default.)
2. It will then *internally rewrite* the request to include the `DirectoryIndex` (if present).

---

*Aside*...

- There's no need to specify `RewriteEngine` more than once in the file. Ideally, it should only occur once at the top. But it can occur anywhere.
- It's strictly invalid to include `RewriteBase` more than once. The last rule wins and controls the whole file. (Although in your current .htaccess file it's not required anyway. `RewriteBase` only affects relative path substitutions.)
- You probably don't need the `<IfModule>` wrappers either. These are only required if the directives they contain are *optional*. Should your site function normally if mod_rewrite is not available? If this was installed on a server where mod_rewrite was not available then it will simply fail silently and try to continue (and maybe break later). Without the `<IfModule>` container it will fail immediately with an error and you'll know quickly what the problem is. WordPress is designed to work on systems without mod_rewrite, but you don't get the same pretty URLs.